# Deploying iphone app remotely

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment

I am developing an iphone application but I do not have an iphone.
But some of my friends have and they willing to try my application (and test a bit) for me.
All tutorils I have seen for deploying require to connect through usb.
I am already a regeistered developer (I got the licence).

Is there a way I can make an installation file and send to them? So they could install and test it.

Or any other way to deply it without having computer and iphone to the same physical place?

Thanx Gezim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the iPhone Developer Program Portal, there is something called [Ad Hoc Distribution](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/distribution.action).

I have not tried this, but by the description, it sounds right:

> Ad Hoc distribution allows you to share your application with up to 100 iPhone or iPod touch users, and to distribute your application through email or by posting it to a web site or server. To prepare your application, the following steps will need to be completed.

There is also a step-by-step guide on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.diawi.com Great tool
It will allow you to upload your archived App to a url, that you can use to download on another device
PS. need provisioning profile